# Formal Proofs for Rust-related Programming Languages Paper

Tags: programming-languages, rust

I've done some PL-related work in Rust that requires some proofs to guarantee the resulting language is free of data races. I'd like to include such work in a paper, but I'm not sure whether I should just formulate the work using operational semantics or whether that approach is becoming outdated, and tools like CoQ are becoming more prevalent.

Can anyone provide some advice on how to go about including such proofs in a PL-based paper submission to conferences such as PLDI and ASPLOS?

Comment: You could skim through a random sample of papers in the proceedings of PLDI from the past 2-3 years, and that might give a sense of what is common...